# GetItemsAsync returns no items using .Net MAUI

Tags: azure-mobile-services, maui

I have migrated some code from the old Azure Mobile Client to DataSync, and the GetItemsAsync method is returning 0 items, although there are items in the database.

Here is the code snippet
 `public async Task<IEnumerable<Configuration>> GetItemsAsync()  { await InitializeAsync(); return await _table.GetAsyncItems().ToListAsync(); }`

If I execute the exact same command through the web portal the correct result is returned.

I am expecting the GetAsyncItems to return a list of items (as it did previous using the Mobile Service Client package).

The call returns a list of 0 items.

If I examine the http traffic, the correct request is sent to Azure and the correct response is returned.

Comment: *"the correct response is returned"* I'm not familiar with the API you are calling; does the response contain the data itself? Are you able to capture the response, and manually verify that the data is properly formatted?

Comment: After further investigation it seems that only the GetAsyncItems is not working. The other methods that find a specific item (by Id), insert a new item, and delete an item all work.

Comment: You should also turn on logging and see what the API is doing behind the scenes.  Also, a key component is whether you are using online or offline mode, and how you are setting up the client.

Comment: How do I enable api logging? And where am I looking for the logs? I am using online mode. I have watched some of your Youtube videos and the only difference I can see with my code is that the back end was built using zumoapiversion 2.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your final comment, you are using the client that uses the v3.0.0 ZUMO-API-VERSION and you are using the v2.0.0 ZUMO-API-VERSION backend.  I'm surprised it is working at all.

When thinking about the ZUMO-API-VERSION

2.0.0 client works with either a 2.0.0 or 3.0.0 server.
3.0.0 client ONLY works with a 3.0.0 server.

So you can update the server, then update the clients, but not the other way round.

Comment: Yes, what you say is correct. When I rebuilt both the client and backend to use zumo 3.0.0 the client now works as expected. The only reason I did not rebuild the server was that I had misplaced my credentials for the app plan in azure.

Comment: How do you pick the ZUMO API VERSION on the client?  I have a server that is 2.0.0 and somehonw my client is 3.0.0 and I ran into a similar problem.  I was getting a 400 Bad Request until I manually changed the header ZUMO_API_VERSION to 2.0.0.  That gave me a 200 OK but only some things worked.  $count is $inlinecount now, etc, so I got an empty result set like the author of this post did.  I want to actually change the client in .NET Maui to be 2.0.0, not fake it.  Any ideas?

Comment: MAUI is incompatible with the 2.0.0 client.